# Stored Procedure to generate insert and create SQL for database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, backup

How can I move a db from one server to another (I only have access to the database with mylittleadmin). Like the title says, I guess the "easiest" way would be by generating SQL with a stored procedure.

I'm using SQL Server 2008 on both servers.

Answer (score 3):

In the codeplex project [Extreme T-SQL Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545871/stored-procedure-to-generate-insert-and-create-sql-for-database) I have written T-SQL procedures to script the content of tables. I just abandoned its use myself in favor of [ssms tools pack](http://www.ssmstoolspack.com/), but the later is no option for you.

When using these procedures in SSMS or VS the main problem is that Microsoft has limits on max column width and max length of output from Print-Statements.

I can't predict, which such limits exist when using mylittleadmin.
It depends on which datatypes and which varchar length you are using. Writing scripts that handle special needs is possible.

Further you need something to script the database objects first and it might be difficult to find something for that, as most people just use SSMS for this purpose. sp_helptext might help to script procedures.

Comment: Warning : endless loop. Extreme T-SQL link points back to this page.

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS, you have the ability to copy or move a database from one instance of SQL Server to another. You can right-click on the database in SSMS, choose Tasks and then Copy Database...

Or, of course, you can simply backup the DB and restore on your target server.

(I have no idea what 'myLitleAdmin' is that you referred to)

Comment: Unfortunately I only have access to the database though a web-tool called myLittleAdmin. This prevents me from connecting to the database from tools like visual studio or sql management (or ssms).

Comment: @Andreas - This is pretty simple then. You can't do it, unless this web-tool allows you to do it (which I doubt).

Comment: Well, someone have to have made a stored procedure to itterate though all tables to create insert and create sql.

Comment: @Andreas - Then you should talk to that person.

Comment: @Andreas Iterate through all the tables would be fairly easy, but you need to go through a LOT of other things to copy a database. To name a few: users, roles, indexes, primary and foreign keys, stored procedures, functions, views, triggers, etc

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make a stored procedure. The easiest way to do it is by right click on your database -->task-->back up and create a backup.

after that you can restore your database on the other server.

Comment: Unfortunately I only have access to the database though a web-tool called myLittleAdmin. This prevents me from connecting to the database from visual studio or sql management.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a license for myLittleAdmin then do as their web states.  It says

**"Purchasing a license gives you unlimited mail support.
Send your request at support@mylittletools.net"**

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found out that you could make a backup of the database in myLittleAdmin. The resulting .bak file was then emailed to me as a link.

Thanks for the comments though, voted up some of them :)